# What is difference between property="og:type" content="website" and property="og:type" content="article"

Tags: facebook-opengraph

We often use `property="og:type" content="website"` or `property="og:type" content="article"` in webpages to show it properly when shared on facebook.

My question is what is main difference between them in terms of visual representation on facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `content="website"` is the default and very general option, while `content="article"` seems to be more specific and concerns an article. [Here](https://ogp.me/#types) you have the documentation, check the title "No Vertical".